# Edit php.ini file

Tags: php, wampserver, php-ini

I want to increase **memory_limit** ,**max_input_time**,**max_execution_time** in `WAMP` server.
There is 3 `php.ini` files.

```
1. C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini<br>
2. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini<br>
3. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\phpForApache.ini<br>
```

so Which `php.ini` file should be edit in `WAMP` server?

Comment: you can try each one and test with a simple php file containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` these 3 ini's seems a messy situation but not difficult to solve :D

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The wampmanager icon, which sits in the system tray has a menu system.

Use that to edit your php.ini file that is used with Apache.

So its

```
(left click ) wampmanager icon -> PHP -> php.ini
```

It could not be simpler.

EDIT/UPDATE:

And now in WAMPServer 3 it has become even easier to change some of the more obvious PHP Settings.

```
(left click) wampmanager icon -> PHP -> PHP Settings
```

and you should see a new menu where you can amend some setting from the menu system as below.

- If there is a Green Tick by an On/Off option then that parameter is set to On.
- If there is a green arrow symbol to the left of an option, that will either open a selectable list OR a dialog where you can enter a value manually to suit yor needs.

[image]

Comment: Yes, It could not be simpler, unless your WAMP is set up on a remote server where you don't have access to the WAMP icon...

Comment: @BillyNair Do you have any access to the remote server?

Comment: Limited access. I can walk over to the IT guys and have them do stuff for me, but I can't access it myself. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Just a minor point, WAMPServer is intended to be a dev tool that sits on your PC. That and a good source management tool like GIT for collecting code from multiple devs into a UAT server and you have a sensible development environment. Maybe you shoudl suggest this to your techies

Comment: Yeah I agree @RiggsFolly, using WAMP as it was intended might be the easier option

Comment: I have wampserver 3.0.6 64bit and there are no PHP in menu.

Comment: @jcubic Yes there is, wampmanager is the hopefully GREEN **W** icon that sits in your system tray

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, you're right I was using right click instead of left one. There are two different menus for the icon.

Comment: @jcubic Yup there are 2 different menus, hence the bracketed **(left click)** instruction

Answer (score 8):

Yo can find that in  **phpinfo()**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

check for `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`  there in the output.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy with a few steps.
Left Click wamp server icon -> PHP -> PHP Settings -> You will see all basic settings here.
Fore example you can increase "upload_max_file_size".
Regards..

Answer (score 0):

```
phpinfo();
```

And check 'loaded configuration file' path.

Comment: Please add sample to show how to find and change the files. tanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini they are all automatically modified.