# sqlsrv extension not showing up in phpinfo.

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using Win server 2k12, php 5.5.12, on wamp. 
Edited php.ini (both on apache dir and php dir) to add php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and the php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll, and configured the extension dir path correctly. Happily, wamp is showing up those extentions at the PHP extension menu,  and after ticking it and restarting all services,  phpinfo is not showing up these changes! Not in the registered PHP streans entry,  no anywhere. 
Do you have any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262606/edit-php-ini-file

Comment: check your error logs. just because something's in the .ini files doesn't mean php can actually load it, or is looking for that particular .ini file.

Comment: So,  you were right.  I checked out my php error log, and it explicitly says that: unable to load... Not a valid win32 application.   Both php and apache are 64 bit,  and i swear god that the extensions are the same.