# upload video with PHP

Tags: php

I am searching for a script to upload a video with PHP, I just uploaded photos and other files with that script, but it isn't working with videos.

```
if(ISSET($_POST['upload']))  
    {
        $fichier = $_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'] ;
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['tmp_name'], 'img/'.$fichier);
                 echo $fichier."  //  ";
    }
    ?>
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input name="multiple_uploaded_files" type="file">
    <input name="upload" value="upload" type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: share your PHP configuration and logs from the server. There is nothing we can do to help you with additional details

Comment: What errors do you get? What file type are you trying to upload and how big is it? The size might make a difference.

Comment: *"Ijust uploaded Photos and other files with that script , but it isnt working with videos."* isn't working how? Any errors? What. Explain the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and post_max_size in your `php.ini` :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying `php.ini` file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply , well im using Wamp server on Windows , how can i do this ??? Thanks.

Comment: @ArfaouiHamouda: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262606/edit-php-ini-file

Comment: @ArfaouiHamouda, You can follow the above link in order to apply those changes

Comment: Cool @ArfaouiHamouda