# html input of type file not uploading .mp3

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-upload, email-attachments

I have an html input of type file. the files that the user uploads are sent to a php code via an ajax.
My html code:

```
<input type="file" id="attachments" name="attachments[]" multiple>
```

My ajax function:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

$.ajax({url: "target.php",
        type:"POST" , 
        data:formData, 
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false ,
        success: function(result){

               //do somthing
         }
});
```

My php code:

```
foreach(array_keys($attachments['name']) as $key) {

    $file_name = $attachments['name'][$key];
    $file_location =  $attachments['tmp_name'][$key];
    echo $file_name.$file_location;
}
```

The problem is that on the php side, when the user uploads an image, the code works just fine, but when i upload a .mp3 file the `$file_location` variable is empty even though the `$file_name` is correct. Anyone knows why this happens ?

Comment: Heve you check upload_max_filesize in php.ini ?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Comment: @Jurik I dont think the problem is in using formdata because the code is working fine with other media jst not mp3

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya where should this file be located if i'm using wamp ?

Comment: @unknown_111 check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262606/edit-php-ini-file) out ;)

Comment: Please refer this one may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262606/edit-php-ini-file

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya you were right the problem is in the upload_max_filesize i found it it was set to 2MB increased it and now it works :)

Comment: @ unknown_111  Please increase those limit and try..

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya it worked.. please write ur comment as an answer so that i can accept it so u take the credit for it

Comment: @unknown_111 glad to help you...

Comment: [PHP error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and [File upload errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the `upload_max_filesize=2MB`  to `upload_max_filesize=32MB` or more in php.ini file.

If you want find the php.ini file then find the help from here [Find the location of php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262606/edit-php-ini-file)